# Replace dependency version number in nuspec with teamcity

Tags: c#, nuget, teamcity

I have a c# solution with two projects

```
solution
    myLib
    myLib.models
```

myLib has a project reference to myLib.Models

TeamCity builds the solution and packages each project into a nuget package. replacing the version number with the build number.

Each project has a nuspec file.

myLib.nuspec defines a dependency on myLib.models. When myLib is consumed by other projects I want nuget to pick up the dependency on the models library and download it and any of its dependencies.

What is the best way to get teamcity to update myLib.nuspec (or other solution) so that the required version of myLib.models in the final package is the same as the build number?

ie

```
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>myLib</id>
    <version>**[teamcitybuildnumber]**</version>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net462">
        <dependency id="myLib.models" version="**[teamcitybuildnumber]**"/>
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin/*/myLib.dll" target="lib/net462" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Did you consider moving to the new sdk-based csproj format (default for .net standard and .net core project types) to get msbiuld-integrated packing? they cover this scenario (without requiring a nuspec)

Comment: I have for some .net standard projects, but I had not seen an option for managing the dependencies that way?

Answer (score 0):

How about [File Content Replacer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/File+Content+Replacer) in Build Features? You can modify anything you want with it.

Comment: yyeessss. I know its possible, but it would not be very targeted